# How to blend 2 accounts together

Tags: discussion

How can I blend two accounts together? One account has 22,000 reputation points and the other account has 1. Both have the same name: Lee Sam

Comment: It doesn't appear that you were successful since this account has accumulated many rep points since. What happened?

Comment: @isherwood It doesn’t seem to work for me. It’s ok, I can still send answers to help people. Thanks anyway.

Comment: We'd like you to regain your reputation. It lends credibility to your answers. Go ahead and ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

The process to merge accounts is specified in [this help article](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts):

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
> sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://diy.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to
> merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team
> will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm
> your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email
> address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

Comment: But I can’t remember the email I used either.

Comment: @LeeSam you only need your current email for that form. SE should reach out and make sure you control both accounts.